# Jquery- Deleting first element from each node

Tags: javascript, jquery

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rqtaz/2/)

I am trying to delete Default from each of the node. I tried following code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "table tbody tr td:nth-of-type(1) select option").first().remove();
});
```

It deleted the element from from the first node. Can someone help me to delete first element from each  node.

Comment: Wow that is confusing @PlantTheIdea ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("table tbody tr td:nth-of-type(1) select option:first-child").remove();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rqtaz/6/

Answer (score 1):

`.first()` returns the first element in the set.

You want to use the `:first-child` selector, which will filter the simple selector you apply it to to only match the first child of the parent:

```
$("table tbody tr td:first-child select option:first-child")
```

This will only match `<option>` elements that are the first child of their respective parents.

You can also use it on the `td`.

Comment: w00t! I beat SLaks :-) `+1` to Naftali ^_^